# IOS - Kill the app if a test fails in instruments

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am currently using `UIAutomation` to *automate our testing* on our iOS apps, through the command line. However I would like to kill the app if a test should fail.

**Is there a way to kill the app, from the command line, or just stop instruments from recording, if a test would fail.**

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do that. It just runs until it is done. Bwoken is the best way I've found to run tests from the terminal. https://github.com/bendyworks/bwoken

Answer (score 1):

Improving the answer:

To build from command line, just use the following command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <WorkspaceName> -scheme <SchemeName> -configuration <Debug/Release/etc> -sdk <iphoneOS7.0/iphonesimulator7.0> clean build
```

**NOTE**: If you use a project and target just replace them instead of the workspace and scheme parameters.

Then, you can run the UIA automation from the command line with this:

**Device**:

```
instruments -v (verbose optional) -t [template] -w [deviceUDID] [application] -e UIASCRIPT [script] -e UIARESULTSPATH [output]
```

**Simulator**:

```
instruments -t [template] [application] -e UIASCRIPT [script] -e UIARESULTSPATH [output]
```

Finally, you can throw an exception when you want your tests to completely stop in case of a failure. I normally just do a **"try-catch"**

```
try {
 UIALogger.logPass(string);
}
catch (e) {
 UIALogger.logError(e.toString());
 UIALogger.logFail(string);
 throw (e);
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: Ultimately what I want to do, is run and install a build from command line and then run the UIAutomation tests from command line as well. As soon as the tests are done, or it fails, the app must be killed and instruments should stop recording

Comment: To use the methods "logIssue" or "logError" does not stop instruments from recording

Comment: Thanx alot for the answer. The problem is though, if one should run it on the simulator and the tests are done or failed, the app still stays open.  Is there a way to kill the app, because if the app stays open it uses a lot of memory if it's running on the sim.

Comment: are you running the test from the command line or using the Instruments IDE?